# Use a SPIN function defined in TopBraid in my Java project

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, spin-rdf

I'm writing my first Java project for Semantic Web using Jena framework.
My ontology was peopled and now I'd like to use some SPIN function (they weren't written by me) in my project.
They are very simple: they receive 2 string arguments and return 1 string. 
I never do this kind of project so I don't know from where I can begin.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks far too many details, but a wild guess may be that you want to use this in the form:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ...
   BIND(spin-function(?param1, ?param2) AS ?result)
   ...
}
```

That assumes that the Jena framework you are using has SPIN installed.